# Lightbox2 Suddenly Not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, lightbox2

About a year ago, I posted here for the first time with a very similar issue: I had just created an image gallery for my art portfolio site, when it was failing in Chrome but performing fine in Microsoft Internet Explorer and Edge.

With some help from very kind (and very patient!) people here, I got Lightbox2 to work in Chrome. It was lovely-- until about a month ago.

Suddenly, only Edge understands the script and Lightbox2 runs fine--
But Chrome seems to have forgotten how to understand and run it.

My coding has not changed since that beginning success--
Could someone take a look and see if something needs to be changed or corrected?

LIVE SITE: art.juniebug.net/portfolio.html

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just had that problem myself. I found it worked in other browsers so I just went to Chrome preferences, under Advanced and clicked "Restore settings to their original defaults"

Fixed it.